# DAG shortest path

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a directed acyclic graph `G = (V,E)` and two distinguished vertices `s` and `t`. Both the edges and vertices are assigned real-valued weights. The weight of a path is defined as the sum of all the edges and vertices on the path. The problem is to find a shortest weighted simple path from `s` to `t`.

(a)  Design a dynamic programming algorithm and briefly describe it.

(b)  Design a greedy algorithm and briefly describe it.

(c)  Provide upper and lower bounds of one of your algorithms as tight as possible.

How do I do this? Can Dijkstra be used?

Comment: This really sounds like a homework problem... What have you done to try to solve the problem, and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I think for greedy algorithm Dijkstra's can be used. I dont know about the rest, sorry mate.